# Checkbox doesnt stay Checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a very weird problem. I am trying to load a "Group" which has a list of devices. The devices exist in a table and a checkmark should appear when the device is inside the group.

My code looks like this:

```
function LoadGroup(Input)
{
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(el => el.checked = false);

    console.log(Input.id);

    GroupData.find(Element => {
        if(Element["ID"] == Input.id)
        {
            Element["Devices"].forEach(Device => {
                Checkmark = document.getElementById(Device["DeviceID"]);
                Checkmark.checked = true
                console.log(Checkmark.checked);
            })
            return true;
        }
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(Element => console.log(Element.checked));
}
```

So a group gets clicked on, I search for the right Group in my data and then go through the devices to set the Checkmark and log the current state. I get 4 true in the console.
After this I query all checkmarks and check if they are checked. I get 3 true one false.

I dont understand what the problem is. He sets all true but then one is false.
Any ideas?

Comment: Dp you havwe two records with the same id?

Comment: No they only exist once, and even if I only set them to check, there is not even an option to uncheck. Unless the first querySelector is async or something.

Comment: We don't have your data, and we don't know what HTML this is operating on. You need to present a proper [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Nothing in the code above is asynchronous.  By the way, instead of `Element["ID"]`, `Element["Devices"]` and `Device["DeviceID"]` use `Element.ID`, `Element.Devices` and `Device.DeviceID`. Where is you declaration of variables? I don't see where you have declared `Checkmark` before using it, so it ends up the the global scope. Please put `"use strict"` at the top of your script file to opt-in for [javascript strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Comment: @some I didn't know you could do that with arrays. I added "use strict" and now it yells at me because I didn't not declare checkmark, very interesting. The error persists sadly.

Comment: In javascript you use `name[index]` to access the element at a specific index in an array. But in javascript arrays can only have numeric indexes. If you have an array `var myArray = [7,2,5]` you can check the length `myArray.length` and get 3. If you assign using a numeric index `myArray[3] = 'Test'` the length is now 4. If you assign something else `myArray['Something'] ='else'` the length doesn't change, and you have created a property on the array. Don't do that. Use an object `var myObject = {something:'else'}` or a map `var myMap=new Map(); myMap.set('something','else')` instead.

Comment: Either you have the same id twice or one of your checkmarks that you get with `document.getElementById(Device["DeviceID"])` doesn¨t match `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')`.